# Error with VMware Player on Windows 7 - Virtual system won´t start

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-machine, vmware-player

my OS is Windows 7 64bit and I have installed VMware Workstation Player 12.1.1-3770994.
I never had problems with it, every time I started the virtual machine it worked without any problems.
But since yesterday the system just won´t start.
I always get the error message

"Error while powering on: VMware Player cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files.  The VMware Authorization Service is not running."

I already found several solutions for it through Google and even here on the website but nothing helped me to get it working again.

I tried to kill all VMware processes in Task Manager and start it again, killed all processes and reboot my PC before I started VMware again, unistalled VMware Player and rebootet my PC but had no success.
Then I uninstalled VMware Player again, clean my registry with CCleaner, rebooted my system, installed again, still no success.
I ran CMD with administrator rights, opened services.msc and restarted the VMware Authorization service.
I also tried the same steps as administrator but it also did not help.
The virtual system I used is Windows XP and I had a backup of the system on my HDD so I deleted the whole folder with the virtual system and copied the backup to the location.
That backup was always working until yesterday.

Now I am at a point where I don´t know what to do anymore and I would be really grateful if someone would have a working solution for it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Install Virtualbox.  Create a new virtual machine.  When it asks to create a hard drive, find the "use existing" option and point it to your existing .vmdk file.  You'll have to do a little set-up for memory and the virtual network card, but you can be up and running in very little time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it did not help.
I downloaded and installed VirtualBox and proceed as you said.
When I then try to open the virtual system with VirtualBox I only get a black windowd and nothing happens.

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: Sorry, I accidently pressed enter before my comment was ready.
Result see above.
I also should mention, in VMware the VMware Authorization Service is running all the time and I also tried to setup a new virtual machine with a XP image.
When I want to start it I get the same error.

Comment: Your last chance is to put the VMware image (and the player) on another computer, and trying it there.  If you get the same result, then your image is the problem.

Comment: I don´t think that the backup is the problem because I use it for long time already and until yesterday exactly that backup was working without any problems on the same version of VMware player.
Yesterday it was the first time I wanted to start it again after two or three weeks and this weas the first time I had the problem.
But you are right, I will try it on another system to eliminate all possible error sources.

Edit: I was able to install a new image in VirtualBox and it seems it´s running properly.
Will then uninstall VMware and use VirtualBox instead.
Thanks alot @codenoire